# AWS S3 access logging bucket does not save any logs

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have 2 buckets: source_bucket and target_bucket. On the source I have enabled Server Access Logging, where as a target bucket I entered my target_bucket with some prefix (/logs/).
Permission for the target_bucket are as follows:

- ACLs are enabled
- S3 log delivery group: write for Objects and read for Bucket ACL

The issue is that logs don't appear in the target bucket. What I missed here?
If I understand correctly once ACLs are activated then Policy doesn't play any role as ACL are being checked for granting permissions, is that correct?

Comment: Did you add the Bucket Policy as shown on [Enabling Amazon S3 server access logging - Amazon Simple Storage Service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/enable-server-access-logging.html)?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein i've also tried with that, but I didn't mentioned it here because I have ACL enabled. In this case does this policy plays any role for me when I have ACLs enabled? Isn't it like either Policy or ACL to restrict access?

Comment: The linked Bucket Policy permits the S3 Logging service to write to the bucket. It is typically a good idea to follow the recommended method. Once you have it working, you are welcome to tweak the configuration.

Comment: The issue in my case was the encryption. I had Default encryption for the taget bucket set to SSE-KMS. When I've changed that to SSE-S3 logs showed up.
The question is why if the first approach it didn't work? Did I miss some permissions to KMS? I will raise another ticket with question as I have a requirement to use KMS Key.

Comment: SSE-KMS issue will be proceed in here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76703550/when-default-encryption-for-s3-bucket-is-set-to-sse-kms-the-access-logs-doesnt