# When Default encryption for S3 bucket is set to SSE-KMS the access logs doesn't show up

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I would like to enable Server access logs for a bucket (named it source_bucket). On the target bucket I've set the permissions:

```
        {
        "Sid": "S3PolicyStmt-Dummy-11111111111111",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Principal": {
            "Service": "logging.s3.amazonaws.com"
        },
        "Action": "s3:PutObject",
        "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::target_bucket/*"
    }
```

other conditions:

- there is no deny access to the logs in the policy of the target_bucket
- S3 Object Lock on target_bucket disabled
- Default encryption on the target_bucket set to SSE-KMS - **and here looks like an issue to me. Once I've changed it to SSE-S3 the logs were presented after some time but with using KMS Key it doesn't.**
  KMS Key has the following policy:

  ```
        {
        "Sid": "Enable IAM User Permissions",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Principal": {
            "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::${account_id}:root"
        },
        "Action": "kms:*",
        "Resource": "*"
    }
  ```

Do I need to set up some additional permissions to make it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The logs are written by the service logs.amazonaws.com so you need to allow the service to decrypt the KMS, add the following policy to the KMS key, make sure to change the region on logs.region.amazonaws.com to the one you are using.

```
  {
    "Effect": "Allow",
    "Principal": {
        "Service": "logs.region.amazonaws.com"
    },
    "Action": [
        "kms:Decrypt*",
        "kms:ReEncrypt*",
        "kms:Describe*"
    ],
    "Resource": "<arn of your KMS key>"
  }
```

Comment: Thank you for the hint - in general that was it but I've changed it a bit. What works for me is the policy on KMS Key in the comment below (due to number of characters limitation)

Answer (score 1):

Thank you furydrive for providing me a hint. What worked for me is the policy below:

```
{
        "Sid": "Allow  aws service to decrypt logs - P2",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Principal": {
            "Service": "logging.s3.amazonaws.com"
        },
        "Action": [
            "kms:Decrypt*",
            "kms:ReEncrypt*",
            "kms:Describe*",
            "kms:GenerateDataKey*",
            "kms:DescribeKey"
        ],
        "Resource": "*"
    }
```

I've added it to KMS Key, I've used.
Service I've used is: logging.s3.amazonaws.com
this is the same, which is used to store data in S3. Other then that I've added 2 more actions following this example:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/AWS-logs-and-resource-policy.html (paragraph: Amazon S3 bucket server-side encryption)